# Tem como reutilizar uma janela com o target do form?

Tags: html, formulário

Sabemos que pela propriedade `target` do formulário HTML podemos dizer se a janela de requisição será aberta na mesma janela ou em uma nova.

Ao utilizar `target="_blank"` é aberta uma nova janela, faz sentido até pelo nome `_blank`, :-)

Temos a seguintes opções

- `_self`: Carrega a resposta no mesmo contexto de navegação que o atual. Este é o valor padrão se o atributo não for especificado.
- `_blank`: Carrega a resposta num novo contexto de navegação anônimo.
- `_parent`: Carrega a resposta no contexto de navegação pai do atual. Se não houver pai, esta opção tem o mesmo comportamento de `_self`.
- `_top`: Carrega a resposta no contexto de navegação raiz (isto é, o contexto de navegação que é ancestral do atual e não tem pai). Se não houver pai, esta opção tem o mesmo comportamento de `_self`.

Mas me surgiu uma dúvida que não encontrei na web, pelo menos de forma clara. Eu poderia utilzar o `window.open` e determinar a mesma janela sempre, mas aí temos o problema de bloqueio de "popups" :-(

Também no meu layout não vi como usar um `<iframe>`, que seria outra opção de reutilização de janelas, pois preciso que seja mostrado em outra janela mesmo.

Exemplo comum:

```
<form id="MeuForm" action="pagina.php" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="pesquisa" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Relatorio"/>
</form>
```

O envio do form vai abrir uma nova aba no navegador a cada requisição, "enchendo" de janelas a tela do usuário e consumindo recursos desnecessários, pois a necessidade é que ele veja somente um relatório por vez.

Será que é possível reutilizar a mesma janela (que já foi aberta em `_blank`) para exibir os próximos resultados de uma requisição de um `<form>`?

Comment: Não acredito que fiz isso, :-) depois de ler a respeito da target acabei fazendo um teste no meu código e resolvi colocar target="relatorio" na propriedade... e pra minha surpresa (mas nem tanto) a requisição é aberta sempre na mesma janela... isso é um comportamento de todos os navegadores? Testei no Chrome, Firefox e Safari, o problema do Safari é que ele não traz a janela pra frete como o Firefox e Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `target` define o *browsing context* da ação. Em um formulário, esse atributo definirá o *browsing context* após a submissão do formulário.

Conforme já se sabe, existem alguns nomes especiais — que começam com o caractere [LOW LINE (U+005F)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005f/index.htm) — como `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, ou `_top`. Você pode saber mais sobre o comportamento deles [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target).

No entanto, a [especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name) do HTML 5 ainda permite que nomes arbitrários sejam usados para definir outros *browsing contexts*, desde que eles não comecem com o caractere que denota os nomes especiais, isto é, [LOW LINE (U+005F)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005f/index.htm).

De forma simples (consulte a tabela da [especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name) para saber mais), quando você define um nome, o comportamento será o seguinte:

- No caso do nome ainda não estiver sendo utilizado, o efeito será o mesmo de `_blank`, isto é, criar um novo *browsing context*.
- No caso do nome já tiver sido utilizado, o efeito será o mesmo de `_self`, isto é, submeter o formulário no contexto já anteriormente criado (desde que tenha o mesmo nome).

Existem outros casos, também colocados na tabela:

[image: Tabela que especifica os nomes do atributo target]

<sup>[Fonte.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name)</sup>